# share marketing using javascript - chartIQ

Tags: javascript, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to build a website which is helpful in share marketing. I am trying to plot a chart in the website, here I have a volume which is coming in every second and is plotted in the graph. Sometimes for one second the volume maybe more than one.

Ex:
**Time          Volume**
10:55:29    -    (2899),
10:55:30    -   (2900),
10:55:30    -   (2902),
10:55:30    -   (2904),
10:55:30    -   (2905),
10:55:31    -   (2907),
The problem is I need to plot the graph only for the last volume(2905) for the time(10:55:30), the other volumes for that particular time should be disregarded.

```
if (volume) { 
    if ((currentTickTime == prevTickTime) && (volume != prevVolume)) {
        volumeArray.push(volume);
        prevVolume = volume;
    } else if (currentTickTime != prevTickTime) {
        volumeTemp = volumeArray[volumeArray.length - 1];
        if (volumeTemp != null || !isNan(volumeTemp)) {
              plotGraph(prevTickData,volumeTemp);
              volumeArray = [];
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code it will plot both the first volume(2899) for the time(10:55:30) and the last volume(2905) for the time(10:55:30). I just need the last volume to be plotted. Can anyone please help me regarding this?

Comment: I recently used a time based charting library called AMCharts which allows you to set it up with a json object and it has a share chart specific to your needs. Have a look at [AmCharts StockChart](https://www.amcharts.com/stock-chart/)

Comment: @Yatin I'm already integrating chartIQ's [chartiq](https://demo.chartiq.com/chartiq.html) libraries into the website. There is one API which takes the volume of the same time and adds all of them and then display it. I'm trying for a workaround so that it takes only the last value of the same time.